# python3 возврат значений из функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
def swap (k1, k2):
    return k2, k1
```

Почему эта функция возвращает кортеж ?

```
def swap (k1, k2):
    return [k2, k1]
```

а если возвращать явно список возвращает список... почему так происходит ?

Comment: Потому что у питона такой синтаксис — при записи выражений через запятую получается кортеж

Comment: встречный вопрос - вызывая эту функцию и присваивая результат одной переменной, что ты ожидал в этой переменной получить?

Comment: Кортежи используется для представления неизменяемой последовательности разнородных объектов. Они обычно записываются в круглых скобках, но если неоднозначности не возникает, то скобки можно опустить.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ну надо же **упаковать** перечисление нескольких переменных в какую-то структуру, вы ведь как проверяете тип возвращаемого значения, наверное, так?

```
print(type(swap(1, 2)))
```

Т.е. вы как бы получаете один объект из функции и проверяете его тип. Потому что если вы сразу присвоите результат работы функции в переменные, то это будут **скалярные** переменные, никакого списка, кортежа или другой коллекции там уже не будет благодаря автоматической **распаковке**:

```
a, b = swap(1, 2)
```

В общем, коллекцию переменных нужно куда-то упаковывать и, в общем-то выбор небогатый: кортеж, список, ну, можно ещё генератор и итератор. Питон выбирает упаковку именно в кортеж, потому что:

- кортеж не изменяемый (результат работы функции уже зафиксирован при возврате, ему не нужно меняться)
- кортеж более оптимальный по хранению данных (именно из-за неизменяемости)

Да, генератор ещё более оптимально расходует память, но там есть свои приколы, в общем, питон считает кортеж оптимальной формой хранения коллекций и использует его по умолчанию для **упаковки** перечисления переменных.

Comment: Спасибо CrazyElf